# Por que o atributo "autofocus" não funciona, vindo de outro documento?

Tags: html

Para poder entender minha situação, estou tentando incorporar um documento (página) em outro documento através do elemento `<iframe>`. Esse documento que estou tentando incorporar contém um formulário que possui um elemento de entrada de texto com o atributo `autofocus` definido, porém ao tentar fazer o seguinte erro aparece no console:

> Blocked autofocusing on a form control in a cross-origin subframe.

**Tradução:**

> Foco automático bloqueado em um controle de formulário em um subquadro de origem cruzada.

Já tentei resolver esse problema usando o atributo `crossorigin` com os valores `anonymous` e `use-credentials`, mas sem sucesso. O erro continua persistindo e não foca no elemento de entrada de texto, tentei também usar os atributo `sandbox` e `allow`, mas sem sucesso.

As minhas dúvidas são:

- **Por que isso está acontecendo?**
- **Como corrigir?**

Comment: Por medida de segurança, o navegador bloqueia o auto foco no *iframe*. Não há como ignorar esse bloqueio sem mexer nas configurações avançadas (*flags*) de segurança.

Comment: Isso é para evitar qq artimanha de clickjacking e essas coisas. É uma questão de segurança mesmo. Talvez com js vc consiga fazer um .focus() no iframe, mas só testando pra ver se é permitido... https://cornerpirate.com/2017/07/06/understanding-clickjacking/ algumas coisa sobe a "prática"

Comment: Não tem o que corrigir, não é um bug, o site dentro do iframe não pertence ao mesmo dominio ou porta que o site que esta embarcando o iframe, tentar acessar algo assim, supondo que fosse possivel, seria falha de segurança, já que poderia manipular outros sites de terceiros de forma indevida, o bloqueio justamente é para proteger sites de terceiros.

Comment: Valeu galera pelo apoio, realmente faz mais sentido agora já que se não houvesse esse "bloqueio" entra várias possibilidades de roubar os dados do usuário.